# Eliminate repeating left joins SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table1:
UID (PK), Root_ID (FK), Branch_ID (FK), Leaf_ID (FK)

Table2:
ID (PK), Name
```

I would like to join the ID in Table 2 to all 3 columns in Table 1 to find out its name. My current code:

```
SELECT X.Name, Y.Name, Z.Name
FROM Table1 AS XX
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS X ON X.ID = XX.Root_ID
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Y ON Y.ID = XX.Branch_ID
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Z ON Z.ID = XX.Leaf_ID
```

Feel like there should be a better way to do this and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which is primary and foreign key in both the tables?

Comment: You aren't joining to 3 columns, your example only joins to Root_ID.  However it look right.

Comment: sql queries do a good job in joining, a three table left join isnt unusual IMO. If you got pkeys on ID in Table2 and fkeys on all the three columns in Table1 then i feel its fine

Comment: Apologies for the confusion but have corrected the code to joining to three columns + indicated the PKs and FKs

Comment: Your code is fine as is. The only thing I would change is to add column aliases so that you don't end up with 3 columns called `Name`. For example: `SELECT X.Name AS Root, Y.Name AS Branch, Z.Name AS Leaf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isnt anything wrong with the query you have. If you are keen to get the first_rows fastest, then it might be (benchmark it) better to use a (select in a select as follows). (Eg if this is a web page where you want the user to be shown the records in a pagination table). But It would depend on the number of records you got in Table1. For a few rows, i would still go with the left join approach you originally have.

If this on the other had was a processing to be done on ALL of the rows,(eg: an ETL job, which has to work with all of the records in table1) then the left join approach is the best.

Thing to watch out for is whether you got fkey contstraints on root_id,branch_id,leaf_id set up

```
SELECT (select name from table2 where id=xx.root_id) as root_name
       ,(select name from table2 where id=xx.branch_id) as branch_name 
       ,(select name from table2 where id=xx.leaf_id) as leaf_name
  FROM Table1 AS XX
```

Comment: if you have fkeys and the values are not null in table1 for root_id then you can substitute the left join with a join

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as :

```
SELECT X.Name, 
CASE X.ID 
 WHEN Root_ID THEN XX.Root_Name 
 WHEN Branch_ID THEN Branch_Name 
 WHEN Leaf_ID THEN Leaf_Name 
END AS [Entity_Name]
FROM Table1 AS XX
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS X 
ON (X.ID = XX.Root_ID OR X.ID = XX.Branch_ID OR X.ID = XX.Leaf_D )
```